# Esta edição devia mesmo ter sido aprovada?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edições-sugeridas

[Esta edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8975) devia mesmo ter sido aprovada? Por melhor que tenha sido a intenção do usuário anônimo, a mudança não foi radical demais? A pergunta ficou mais ampla do que já era. Talvez até funcionasse como uma pergunta separada, apesar de ter altas chances de acabar fechada também.

O que acham?

Answer (score 4):

Ao ver a edição, entendi que o usuário anônimo foi o próprio autor da questão, até porque não faz sentido aqueles detalhes vindo de outra pessoa. Visto que ele teve o esforço ao tentar esclarecer o problema, eu achei correto aceitar as mudanças. Não vi sentido em rejeitar a edição, já que está em concordância com o problema.

Antes ele perguntava:

> Como criar um instalador utilizando o NSIS?

e alterou para:

> Como criar um instalador para programas?

Ainda se trata do mesmo problema "Como criar um instalador", e o `NSIS` é para criar um *instalador de programas* para Windows.

Em relação ao conteúdo da questão, os detalhes giram em torno do mesmo problema que levou ele a criar a pergunta, eliminando a especificação do `NSIS` também.

Talvez eu tenha me equivocado, mas acho que o problema dele ainda continua o mesmo.

Comment: PS: Edição de autor da publicação não vai para a fila de análises.

Comment: Por isso foi uma edição anônima, @Math. Provavelmente o usuário em questão esqueceu de logar ou coisa assim.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge entendi o ponto de vista

Comment: Pode ser que seja o próprio autor, mas pode ser que não. Teve um caso recente do autor editando de outra conta, mas no resumo da edição ele disse que era o autor (bom, e eu acreditei). Neste caso não vi indícios disso, aquelas informações são bem genéricas. O que me chamou a atenção foi que a pergunta ficou mais aberta (antes era "como fazer um instalador com NSIS", e virou "como fazer um instalador").

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo que a edição não contribuiu muito para o solucionamento do problema, mas pareceu haver mais detalhes. Aliás, alguém já reverteu a questão.